# Anyone with Compaq G60 Laptop; Blind bios walk-through for a "to VGA" first?

Tags: laptop, bios, vga

One of my laptops has a broken screen. But I cant really afford to get a new one yet.

Just wondering if anyone has a [G60 HP/Compaq] laptop, that you might post a key by key blind walk-through to changing to VGA first, and save.

I figure this would be immensely handy for the someone else too.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have a function key that switches between internal and external monitor? That's what I did with my netbook before I replaced the screen.

Comment: That key will work after the bios, It will not set it to init VGA on boot.

Comment: Doesn't it remember the setting for the next boot, though?

Comment: no it does not. Granted, its a crappy laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is such a option ?

I went to the manual looking for ways to help, but found no such configuration

http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02985882.pdf

Comment: I couldnt find anything at all about the bios in that

Comment: I think they are calling it 'the setup utility'

I've seen a couple of manuals that do that